# Why doesn't std::generate return state similar to std::for_each?

Tags: c++, stl

`std::generate` returns `void`:

```
template<typename ForwardIterator, typename Generator>
void generate(ForwardIterator first, ForwardIterator last, Generator gen);
```

While `std::for_each` returns `Function`:

```
template<typename InputIterator, typename Function>
Function for_each(InputIterator first, InputIterator last, Function f);
```

SGI's [documentation](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/for_each.html) suggests that `for_each`'s result is useful for returning any state which may have mutated during the algorithm. Isn't the same true for `generate`?  Is this an oversight, or is there a rationale for the difference in interface?

Comment: `for_each` has the ability to "read" the contents of the container.  `generate` simply overwrites the content; what would be the benefit of returning anything?

Comment: Suppose I passed a random number generator to generate.  Returning the state of the RNG would be useful.

Comment: True.  But this would be invariant of the container content.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One significant difference is that whilst `for_each` operates on the container content, `generate` simply overwrites it.  So the function object passed to `generate` can collect no information about the container content, so there'd be little reason to return it afterwards (its final state is invariant of the container content).

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that it's to allow the predicate to be copied in `generate`'s work so maintaining an internal state isn't always going to work right. `for_each` actually only mutates one instance of the predicate and then returns a copy of it.

When you usually do is have the predicate store a reference to an external state object and then check that when generate is done.

```
StateHolder state;
Generator generator(state); // Pass by reference.
std::generate(c.begin(), c.end(), generator);
// Now you can check the state object for whatever you need.
```

Comment: The predicate cannot be copied at will; see this article at Dr. Dobbs: http://drdobbs.com/184403769.